# ¿Cómo crear un intervalo de fecha de inicio hasta una fecha final con python-dateutil?

Tags: python, date

Estoy utilizando esta función con la que deseo sacar las fechas con un día inicial y un día final:

```
from dateutil.rrule import rrule, MONTHLY

def date_fechas(desde, hasta):
    desde = datetime.date(desde.year, desde.month, desde.day)
    hasta = datetime.date(hasta.year, hasta.month, hasta.day)
    datos = [dt for dt in rrule(MONTHLY, dtstart=desde, until=hasta)]
    return datos
```

pero no me esta funcionando, quisiera saber si es porque me falta alguna librería o algo esta mal en mi código.

Comment: Fernando, dices que no está funcionando, ¿te está arrojando algún error? Tampoco entiendo muy bien lo que estás tratando de hacer, necesitas todas las fechas que hay entre una fecha inicial y otro final, ¿es eso?

Comment: Si, necesito las fechas de un rango inicial y un rango final

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pues con la función [`rrule`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/rrule.html#dateutil.rrule.rrule) no lo vas a lograr, esa función es para usar reglas con respecto a las fechas.

De lo que si podrías sacar ventaja es de la función [`relativedelta`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/relativedelta.html#dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta) para que puedas hacer un poco de aritmética con las fechas y calcular tu rango:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta


def rango_fechas(desde, hasta):
    rango = []
    # Calculamos la diferencia de los días
    dias_totales = (hasta - desde).days
    for days in range(dias_totales + 1): 
        fecha = desde + relativedelta(days=days)
        rango.append(fecha)
    return rango
```

Probemos la función:

```
>>> desde = datetime.date(2015, 1, 5)
>>> hasta = datetime.date(2015, 1, 25)
>>> rango_fechas(desde, hasta)
[datetime.date(2015, 1, 5),
 datetime.date(2015, 1, 6),
 datetime.date(2015, 1, 7),
 datetime.date(2015, 1, 8),
 datetime.date(2015, 1, 9),
 datetime.date(2015, 1, 10),
 datetime.date(2015, 1, 11),
 datetime.date(2015, 1, 12),
 datetime.date(2015, 1, 13),
 datetime.date(2015, 1, 14),
 datetime.date(2015, 1, 15),
 datetime.date(2015, 1, 16),
 datetime.date(2015, 1, 17),
 datetime.date(2015, 1, 18),
 datetime.date(2015, 1, 19),
 datetime.date(2015, 1, 20),
 datetime.date(2015, 1, 21),
 datetime.date(2015, 1, 22),
 datetime.date(2015, 1, 23),
 datetime.date(2015, 1, 24),
 datetime.date(2015, 1, 25)]
>>> desde = datetime.date(2015, 2, 27)
>>> hasta = datetime.date(2015, 3, 4)
>>> rango_fechas(desde, hasta)
[datetime.date(2015, 2, 27),
 datetime.date(2015, 2, 28),
 datetime.date(2015, 3, 1),
 datetime.date(2015, 3, 2),
 datetime.date(2015, 3, 3),
 datetime.date(2015, 3, 4)]
```

Usando listas de comprehensión es posible reducir bastante la función a esto:

```
def rango_fechas(desde, hasta):
    return [desde + relativedelta(days=days) for days in range((hasta - desde).days + 1)]
```